# Reference a local WSDL in a .NET Core SOAP service

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, .net-core, wcf-configuration

I have a SOAP service defined by a local `.wsdl` file that I want to use to generate a .NET Core *Connected Service* in Visual Studio 2017.

My `ConnectedService.json` looks something like this:

```
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.20119.1312",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "Uri": "C:\\Path\\MyUsername\\LocalRepository\\soap-service.wsdl",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

The problem is that this completely breaks for anyone else who accesses this source and doesn't put their local repository in the exact same location as I do.

I want the reference to be relative to the project, like `"Uri": "soap-service.wsdl"`, but that results in an error:

[image: Error referencing local file]

How can I configure `ConnectedService.json` so that it finds the local file relative to the .NET project?

Comment: I added a suggestion for relative paths to the development team: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3264